# How to get around This Content cannot be displayed in a frame? (Youtube issue)

Tags: php, youtube-api

I'm trying to keep a database of posted videos on a site I am currently developing. To be able to do this I have to store the URLs of the videos into a database and then I call the url from the database using php and sql by doing this bare in mind I am using this from a php defined area on my homepage. If I use this code it works on other video post sites!

`echo '<iframe width="640" height="390" src="', $row['Post_URL'],'"frameborder="0" allowFullScreen></iframe>';`

This will not work it says content cannot be displayed in a frame but if I do this it works.

`<?php


echo '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/wardQ7W8hPU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';


?>`

why does the one work properly and the other not? what is a way around this so I can call from the database into php and echo it out so it will display properly on the page?

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with PHP and MySQL. For debugging this, it suffices to compare the generated HTML. Have a look at the value of $row['Post_URL']. Chances are, that the video you want to display has different settings then the one in your second example.

Comment: Just for being pedantic, you have `allowfullscreen` in your static example and then `allowFullScreen` in your dynamic(PHP) example. Agree with cebewee however, you should check the output value from PHP.

Comment: if the posted source is an accurate representation, it appears that in the first example you do not have a space between the quote and frameborder where as in the second example you do.  Also the answer below has space between the quote and frameborder.

Answer (score 5):

I got the same problem today. As stated in one of the comments, the problem is the url used...

The iframe embed only works with urls looking like:

```
http://www.youtube.com/embed/[video_id]
```

Most of people are using the "share" feature, that generates minified urls like:

```
http://youtu.be/[video_id]
```

However, if you look into the "embed" feature, you'll notice that it generates an iframe with src urls like the first example.

So to answer the question, when using iframes to embed, use the src url like the first example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<iframe width="640" height="390" src="<?php echo $row['Post_URL'] ?>" frameborder="0" allowFullScreen></iframe>
```

OR this

```
  <?php
      echo "<iframe width='640' height='390' src='{$row['Post_URL']}' frameborder='0' allowFullScreen></iframe>";
  ?>
```

OR this

```
<?php
    echo "<iframe width='640' height='390' src='" . $row['Post_URL'] . "' frameborder='0' allowFullScreen></iframe>";
?>
```

they all are the same and will do the same process.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I really appreciate the quick responses. I have tried everything everyone has suggested and recommended with actually the same result as my code was getting... so evidently I'm going to have to look at a different way to bring the code in maybe store the whole embed code in my database then echo it though php like the examples given to me. Thanks again!

Comment: the address in the embed video code of the video i was trying to use is different from where I was trying to get the address from to play the video <Br> http://www.youtube.com/embed/wardQ7W8hPU <br> see the /embed ? thats what was causing my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing this with dynamic data and it's easier for the client to use the youtube Share link.
So... it's then just a matter of getting the youtube video ID from that url.

```
// we can't use the "share" link so need to just get the video ID
$youtubePath = parse_url($youtubeShareLink,PHP_URL_PATH);
$youtubeId = str_replace('/','',$youtubePath);
```

and now we can use the ID in an iframe (adjust width and height per embed options in youtube)

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/<? echo $youtubeId; ?>?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```